# facet_grid problem : input string 1 is invalid in this locale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create facet grid with the following code

```
p <- ggplot(melted,aes(factor(country))) + geom_bar() +opts(axis.text.x =   theme_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1)) 

p + facet_grid(. ~ provider)
```

but I always get the following error:

Error in sub("^[^:]+: ([^\n]+)\n[0-9]+:(.*)$", "\1\2", expr) : 
   input string 1 is invalid in this locale

I do not have any idea what I am doing wrong. also tried to factor my facet, which doesn't work either.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I fixed this one on my own. Here's the solution. My locale was set to 
[1](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.biology.informatics.conductor/28248) "de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8"

which I checked with

```
Sys.getlocale()
```

According to the b[ioconductor mailinglist](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.biology.informatics.conductor/28248), locale should be set to C. This is what I did

```
Sys.setlocale(locale="C")
```

Et voilà the faceting worked just like it used to. I have no clue how the locale changed, but that's how you can change it whenever this problem occurs.

HTH someone else too.

Comment: Just an addition to this comment, which helped me a lot!

Is not really necessary to change all locals, this was enough for me: 
locale <- Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "C")

I've used the locale variable because was using this inside a map.R file (for Hadoop Streaming + R) and the command has the "side effect" of printing "C".